# Java - How to complete this if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

```
while(true) {
    a=0;
    b=0;

    if(condition){
       a++;
    }else{
       b++;
    }

}
```

I have this code and I don't know how to complete it. I want it to leave the loop after a and b reach some amount. Please help.

Comment: Do you know the break statement?

Comment: You should probably use a `for` loop instead of an infinite `while` for this.

Comment: "I want it to leave the loop after a and b reach some amount." -> this is a stopping condition, which should be defined inside your `while(condition)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration of `a` and `b` must be outside of the `while` loop. Otherwise, they will always be 0. You can change the condition of the `while` loop to `a < amount || b < amount` which means a and b have not yet reached the amount.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

while (a < amount || b < amount) {
    if (condition) {
       a++;
    } else {
       b++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have improved my answer. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use a flag boolean instead of while(true) :

```
boolean flag = true;

while (flag) {
    // your loop
    if (a == the amount you want && b == the amount you want)
        flag = false;
    condition ? a++ : b++;
}
```

Comment: Instead of the flag you could just use the while condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=b=0;
while(a<someValue || b<someValue){
if(condition){
   a++;
}else{
   b++;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 while (a != some_value || b != some_value2){
    a++; b++;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while(true) {
    a=0;
    b=0;

    if(a >= your condition && b >= your condition){
       break;
    }else{
       a++;
       b++;
    }

}
```

Comment: With `a=0;` and `b=0;` inside the loop, will be endless loop unless "your condition" is  negative number.

Comment: I jsut wanted to show the break manipulation. I just copy past the exemple above.
And about the >= it was an exemple too. Depend what you want, you need to select the good operator

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

while (b < amount) {
    if (a < amount) { // increment a if it is less than amount
       a++;
    } else if(b < amount) { // Now increment b, increment b if it is less than amount
       b++;
    }
}
```